# Построение предложения [1]

Tags: причастия, деепричастный-оборот, порядок-слов

Правильный ли порядок слов в предложении (причастие и деепричастие в придаточной части)? Мне кажется, да, но не уверен до конца.

> Художника вдохновляло то, как танцевала проживающая в этом доме с последних выходных девушка, плавно размахивая руками в разные стороны, словно приземляющийся лебедь.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Художника вдохновляло то, **как** танцевала проживающая в этом доме с последних выходных девушка — **плавно размахивая руками в разные стороны, словно приземляющийся лебедь**.

Здесь **пояснительные** отношения между союзным словом КАК и деепричастным оборотом.

Розенталь [§ 23. Пояснительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119)

При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто ставится тире: Он обладает **особой** способностью — всё делать вовремя. Разговор шёл **один** — о погоде.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны варианты:

Художника вдохновляло то, как танцевала, плавно размахивая руками в разные стороны, словно приземляющийся лебедь, проживающая в этом доме с последних выходных девушка.

Художника вдохновляло то, как танцевала, плавно размахивая руками в разные стороны, словно приземляющийся лебедь, девушка, проживающая в этом доме с последних выходных .

Художника вдохновляло то, как девушка, проживающая в этом доме с последних выходных, танцевала, плавно размахивая руками в разные стороны, словно приземляющийся лебедь.

Comment: Может, грамматически правильно, но нечитабельно.